# Where is the limit.h file that defines the template numeric_limits

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, debian

So, I am trying to locate the limit.h file that has the numeric_limits defined.
I seem to find all different flavors of the limit.h but not the defined one, as
shown in 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits

I am on debian distro.

Here is what I have done so far. I created a `main.cpp` with only `#include <limits>`
Did a g++ verbose build to find all the include path:
`g++ -v main.cpp -o tryout`.
Now I see that `/usr/include`
and `usr/lib` has bunch of limits.h files. But none of them seem to have the template definition I am looking for

in `/usr/include/`
`% find -name limits.h` returns the following :
    ./c++/4.4/tr1/limits.h
    ./limits.h
    ./linux/limits.h

in `/usr/lib`
    `% find -name limits.h` returns the following:
    ./perl5/Tk/pTk/compat/limits.h
    ./gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3/include-fixed/limits.h
    ./gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/include-fixed/limits.h

So where is the `std::numeric_limits` template located. How do I find that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the reference page shows, `std::numeric_limits` is defined in the header `<limits>`, not `limits.h`. You can find where it is by asking the preprocessor, for example:

```
~$ cat test.cc
#include <limits>

~$ g++ -E test.cc -o - | grep limits | grep gcc | tail -1
# 841 "/opt/swt/install/gcc-4.7.2/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/limits" 3
```